# Install VLC on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2

Tags: rhel, vlc

I want to install VLC Media Player on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2. My system is subscribed to the Red Hat Network.

I am following [these steps](http://knowledge-db.info/2014/09/13/install-vlc-on-centos-7/) and have run into dependency issues.

[image]

I downloaded and built the two missing dependencies from source however I am still getting the same errors when I run `yum install vlc`.

[image]

Comment: Did you build and install source RPMs, or just source? SRPMs would result in RPMs that yum would know about; plain source would not.

Comment: Just source for the last two

Comment: Then you'll have to tell yum to ignore dependencies (since the dependencies are installed, just not with RPM)

Comment: Correction -- looks like you have to get the RPM files and install the with `rpm ... --no-deps`. Yum doesn't ignore dependencies.

Comment: Could you copy the text instead of images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to install VLC by setting `notify_only=0` in `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf`.

[image]

During the installation more repos were enabled and checked for dependencies which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

I had to enable these repos to get it done.

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-rpms 
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```